# LM317LM as a current source

Tags: current, current-source, lm317

I have been using LM317L as a current source for generating 2-50mA current for a load, by following the datasheet, P14:
[image]

So far so good, but now I have come across LM31L-n, particularly LM317LM/NOPB, which also comes in 8-Pin SOIC form which in the datasheet states that 4 of the pins are Vout.
My question is that is it possible to use those 4 outputs to generate 4 different current sources by using different resistors on each line, given that they are in the allowed range and all together will not pass 100mA, doesn't seem right or am I missing something?

My goal is to have multiple current sources within the given range, so if I can have less IC, it would be great.

[datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317l-n.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1591131202122)

Thanks and regards,
Pat

Comment: Those multiple pins are for heatsinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The 8-pin package from page 3 of the datasheet.*

Since there is only one ADJ pin you hopes are dashed. It's one LM317 inside with V<sub>OUT</sub> connected to four pins. They'd be labelled differently otherwise.

There are a couple of other clues:

- There's only one ADJ pin. You can only set one voltage / current.
- To do what you were hoping for you'd need 4 × ADJ, 4 × V<sub>OUT</sub> and V<sub>IN</sub>. That's nine pins, the chip only has eight and two of them are NC (not connected).

Sorry.

Comment: Thank you, could you recommend some alternatives? :)

Comment: You're not going to find anything simpler than 4 × LM317 and 4 × adjust resistors, I suspect, but have a look at the [AL5809](http://lednique.com/power-supplies/al5809-constant-current-driver/) chips.

Comment: Thanks, ill check it out.